# Virtual keyboard for chromium in kiosk mode (fullscreen)

Tags: virtual-keyboard

For a kiosk application on a touch screen device we use a web app running inside chromium browser in kiosk mode (`--kiosk`), which implies full screen. We are now seeking a solution to provide users with a virtual keyboard.

What we have tried:

Chrome-Extensions: There are a lot but all of them seem to fail as soon as an input field is inside an iframe, which makes them unusable for our scenario

Linux virtual keyboards ( We are on Ubuntu 14.04 / Openbox window manager) : Florence, Onboard, matchbox keyboard, tried any I could google ;-): They all fail as soon as the browser is in full screen mode.

Javascript / jQuery Plugins: see above / Chrome Extensions (iframe problem)

So the question is: Is there a way to tell Openbox (or another window manager, switching to another wm could be an option) that the keyboard window should be placed above the full screen browser window? Or any other suggestions are welcome.

The closest solution right now is to run chromium not in kiosk mode but maximized without window decorations (so it looks like fullscreen), then "Onboard " is a good choice, but all the other features from kiosk mode (e.g. disabled context menu etc.) are missing...

Thanks a lot for any ideas on this subject!

Comment: Check out my jQuery plugin: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard; I know I've helped some others set it up for a kiosk.